# Bug in compiler?

Tags: java

May I ask that in Java, after I highlight `(resultSet != null && resultSet.next())` in `IF` statement and `DISPLAY` in debugging mode (with breakpoint), it appears that it won't enter the `IF` statement although the result returns `TRUE`?

```
    try {
            conn = new BaseDA().getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(_sqlIns);
            stmt.setInt(1, obj.getYrStart());
            stmt.setInt(2, obj.getAge());
            stmt.setDouble(3, obj.getBasicSaving());

            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
              //can't get in after right-click DISPLAY
            if (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()){
                result = resultSet.getString(_colnm1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your title *bug in compiler* IMHO not the best... seems more probable you made some mistake like.... no results in `resultset`?

Comment: even though your resultSet is not null,resultSet.next()will return false.because of that,if block not executed.when you make debugging,what value in resultSet?

Comment: Add some console and use **getRow()** to see how many row you have recover with you query.

Comment: @Jordi Castilla Hi, i got only 1 result in return to the resultset from a insert SQL statement (OUTPUT). will it make any diff?

Comment: @SicaYoumi of course, you're not iterating it... check my  answer and documentation liked

Comment: @sawyinwaimon Hi, because of that i put additional resultset != null to justify in case resultSet.next() is False. Did i make any sense? Sorry I'm a newbie in API

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most of the time people suspects a compiler bug it's actually not - instead it's a mistake done by the programmer and reducing the example makes it easier to pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no *compiler* bug. Why would you think so, if the *debugger* acts weirdly?

Second, [`stmt.executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) cannot return null, so remove that null check. See javadoc:

> Returns a `ResultSet` object that contains the data produced by the query; **never `null`**

Calling [`resultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) move the "cursor" to the next row. See javadoc:

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method `next` makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

So, if you've just stepped over the `executeQuery()` call in the debugger, the `resultSet` is positioned before the first row.

If you then ask the debugger to *evaluate* the expression (using "Display"), the debugger will actually *call* the `next()` method, which would advance to the first row and return `true`.

When you then subsequently step over the `if` statement, it will call the `next()` method again, which will try to advance to the second row of the result set. Assuming only one row was returned, it will return `false` and your `if` block is skipped.

So, by evaluating the expression in the debugger, *you* caused the skip of the one-and-only returned row.

In short: **Beware side effects of evaluating expressions in the debugger**. You should not evaluate anything that has side effects. Only evaluate idempotent methods, e.g. getters, `toString()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, your asnwer save me from my frustration. The **next()** method is very dangerous if not understand fully. like me..haha thanks for explaining to me. I thought is was a bug in "Display" in debugger. haha didn't expect it will trigger the **next()**method ^_^ peace out.

Answer (score 2):

First of all... **NO THERE IS NO BUG IN THE COMPILER!!!**

Second: are you sure you get some results?? *If yes continue*

**Solution:** you're not iterating the `resultSet` according [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) suggests, so you will get only ONE result instead of complete set of results:

```
while (rs.next()) {

}
```

So you must:

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    result = resultSet.getString(_colnm1);
}
```